# Struggling with setting images and div's with percentages

Tags: html, css

Using constrain proportions, I am trying to replicate the experience of using a laptop, currently on Windows Vista. I would like the laptop image to scale depending on the screen size and anything inside the #Screen to be relative to the screen size.

At the moment, the height of the .MenuBar is 4% as that is roughly the percent it should be, however I do not know how to have the tar at the bottom of the #Screen as I thought this would be margin-top:96%;, yet my current percent of margin-top:56%; shows the bar roughly at the bottom.

I would like to know how to not only scale my laptop depending on the users screen via using percentage for example, but to include the image being scaled and both to be centered. The screen to be positioned behind the laptop image as the screen has been cut out of the laptop image to replicate screen positioning and lastly everything inside of the screen to be relative to the screen.

I am a little confused and I hope my above wording is not confusing , my apologies if this is the case.

website View: https://tornhq.com/Laptop/index.html

JSFiddle View: http://jsfiddle.net/JAjMY/

Source Code View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }

            #Laptop {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:545px;
                height:373px;
                background:url(images/laptop.png) no-repeat;
                z-index:1;
            }
            #Laptop .Screen {
                position:absolute;
                width:395px;
                height:221px;
                margin-top:26px;
                margin-left:75px;
                background:#03F;
                z-index:2;
            }
            #Laptop .MenuBar {
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                height:4%;
                margin-top:56%;
                background:url(images/Microsoft/Vista/MenuBar.png) repeat-x;
                background-size:100% 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
        <div id="Laptop">
            <div class="Screen">
                <div class="MenuBar">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Best Regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

to begin I would suggest a few things:

- First off, to get the image to scale to the size of the user's screen, set `width` and `height` of your `body` and `html` elements to 100%. You can then scale the `#Laptop` element by setting a percentage `width` and `height` as well.
- To get the screen to position correctly, make sure the `#Laptop` div is `position: relative` or `position: absolute`. I used `relative` to make it easier to center the laptop by applying `margin: 0 auto`.
- You can now position your screen and all of its parts on the `#Laptop` by using `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` properties.

Check out the jsFiddle I put together:

http://jsfiddle.net/m3ta/y4Exs/

Keep in mind this is just one way to reach the desired outcome, there are other options.

Comment: Thank you for your time spent in following up my questions. I've rated your answer up as you've given some valid points, some which I should have known, yet I never even thought about doing!